# Jquery, add class to steps

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of stepped divs, each one contains a done button which when clicked takes them back to the default start one. This is the jQuery I wrote, but there must be a better way to do this?

```
$( ".reset1" ).click(function() {
    $("#start").addClass( "active" );
    $("#step1").removeClass( "active" );
});
$( ".reset2" ).click(function() {
    $("#start").addClass( "active" );
    $("#step2").removeClass( "active" );
});
$( ".reset3" ).click(function() {
    $("#start").addClass( "active" );
    $("#step3").removeClass( "active" );
});
$( ".reset4" ).click(function() {
    $("#start").addClass( "active" );
    $("#step4").removeClass( "active" );
});
$( ".reset5" ).click(function() {
    $("#start").addClass( "active" );
    $("#step5").removeClass( "active" );
});
```

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: Here it is here https://jsfiddle.net/jqbtqy2e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what parts of the code are repeated and see how you can pull them outside into one single function. Also, you can take a look at how you can minimize your number of events.

For each `reset` element add the plain class `reset` and have your event fire whenever any reset button is pressed. You should also look at how to utilize HTML attributes - like the `data` attribute which can be [read about here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). So you have the step index stored in a custom HTML `data` attribute `data-reset`

```
<div class="reset" data-reset="1">Reset Div</div>
<div class="reset" data-reset="2">Reset Div</div>
...etc
```

Now you can minimize your JavaScript to make it more efficient, and use jQuery's `data` function to get your step index -

```
$(document).on('click', '.reset', function(){
    $('#start').addClass('active');
    $('#step' + $(this).data('reset')).removeClass('active');
});
```

More on jQuery's data attribute [can be read here](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: I think you are missing the point that this probaly goes above and beyond the level of understanding that this person has of basic javascript/programming. The fact that the OP didn't consider a fucntion for this reflects that. Maybe add some explanation someone new to javascript could use to understand what you wrote?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets how is this above anyone's understanding? in fact I think your answer is much more confusing than mine. But I will add some clarification

Comment: This is what I need. I have this working. I just need to 100% understand what its doing. I guess $(this) refers to the current selected step clicked on, im still working out the data attributes. Thanks for this

Comment: @WebblyBrown Yes, you are correct. In jQuery whenever you are working with an event function and use the `this` selector it refers to the current element that the event was fired off of. If you have any other questions about the code, I'll be here

Answer (score 2):

There must be a better way...
[image: There is a better way isn't there?]

Put it in a function for easy maintenance,
then call that function in a loop at a point of your choosing. For example `document.ready();`

```
function setReset(num) {
    $(".reset"+num).click(function() {
        $("#start").addClass("active");
        $("#step"+num).removeClass("active");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i=1; i<6; i++) {
        setReset(i);
    }
});
```

This way you can call this function any time you want, with any variable you want.

Now I advise you to learn a bit about functions, loops and scopes whilst you are at it, because your question reflects a lack of basic understanding of programming that could really help you with future issues like this.

Comment: Very tempted to downvote this post due to the animated gif and tone of the last paragraph...

Comment: what, giving advice isn't allowed? The OP is very clearly new to programming, that is reflected by the question alone. I'm giving him pointers where he can broaden his horizon. And the gif, for heavens sake, you have no sense of humor? Op said there must be a better way. you have never googled there must be a better way on google images? No sense of humor it seems

Comment: Well this has escalated quickly, I have wiped my eyes dry

Comment: [We hate fun.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) The last paragraph, while possibly/probably correct, comes across as being a little condescending...  Hopefully that wasn't your intent. Just trying to give a quick pointer, feel free to edit or disregard as you see fit.

Comment: I come from the viewpoint we're all professionals/nerds  and we like to get the job done.  A bit of cynical humor lives among us,  but also a deep sense of being too the point.  We're not tumblr i hope where we would use 20 sentences or more to describe what we mean in the hope to not offend anyone. At least i hope not

Comment: Clarification on the provided link: "We hate fun" has grown into a bit of a meme/mantra on some parts of the network, and is often used as an explanation for why we try to suppress comedy and maintain a level of professionalism.

Comment: Look at my profile :-p I've been around for a while.  I know; -)

Comment: OK right so here is a fiddle of this in action with my code, give us a hand, yes im very new to programming :) https://jsfiddle.net/jqbtqy2e/

Comment: I have to disagree as well with the last comment, not in terms of the OP being a beginner, rather on the fact that you need to learn loops and scopes alone. In my solution I referenced CSS attribute selectors which should be an efficient way to solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a `reset` class to each `reset1`, `reset2`etc. element and then:

```
$(".reset").click(function() {
    $("#start").addClass("active");

    // remove the word `step` from the id, could use a regex too
    var i = $(this).attr('id').replace('step', '');
    $("#step" + i).removeClass("active");
    // return false ?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how can I do this in a better way using jQuery, first thing that comes to mind is [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), second is [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) for your class, such as the begins with selector.

Check it out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Listen for click on all elements whose class starts with reset
    $("[class^='reset']").click(function(){
        // Add/Remove the active class accordingly
        $("#start").toggleClass("active");
        // Grab the element whose ID is step#
        // The # is determined by the index of the clicked reset element
        // The index starts at 0, so we add 1 to match the #
        $("#step" + ($(this).index() + 1)).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Aaaaand [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/uh8wjmp4/) for your enjoyment!

The important thing to know about `toggleClass` is how the state of the element will change from its inception. If you must use add/remove class, then its because the solution is not as simple as an on and off switch where you add/remove class depending on a condition.